# What is the optimum size for images on the ipad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, three20

I have built a photo app for the iphone which has albums of high resolution images that the user can flick through.  It's based on Three20 and the TTThumbsViewController.

The images are currently mostly 2048x2048 or thereabouts but this seems too large given the screen is only 1024x768.

Is there any value in leaving them at the higher resolution or should I drop them to 1024x768?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to allow some kind of zoom/pan functionality, then there is value leaving them at a higher resolution. Otherwise there isn't: they take up more space and need to be scaled down anyway.

Just a note: scaling up or down by a couple of pixels is bad for sharp edges. Try to avoid this.